# Vue v-for each occurrence of a record in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to display information from a website. The website tracks traffic jams and other maintenance work. I want to collect only the traffic jams and display them in a for each.

The code uses Axios to get the data from a static url: https://www.anwb.nl/feeds/gethf. I have already figured out how to obtain the information from this file:

```
{{roadEntries[0].events.trafficJams[0].from}} => To get where the jam starst
{{roadEntries[0].events.trafficJams[0].to}} => To get where the jam ends.
```

```
 export default {
        name: "Melding",
        data() {
            return {
                datum: {},
                roads: {},
                informations: {},
                roadEntries: {},
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            const axios = require('axios');
            const api = 'https://www.anwb.nl/feeds/gethf';

            // Make a request for a user with a given ID
            axios.get(api).then((response) => {
                this.informations = response.data;
                this.datum = response.data.dateTime;
                this.roadEntries = response.data.roadEntries;
                this.roads = response.data.roadEntries;
            })
        }
    }
```

template:

```
   <div>
        <p>{{ datum }}</p>
        <hr>
        {{roadEntries[0].road}}
        {{roadEntries[0].events.trafficJams[0].from}}
        {{roadEntries[0].events.trafficJams[0].to}}
    </div>
```

I did once manage to put the "from" in data(), but looping that just gave me a loop of each letter in the word.

Also, the file containing the information contains a few arrays, with makes it hard to work with it. The "datum" data was easy to collect because it was just one static string.

Could someone show/explain to me how I can loop trough each record in the file and display them each in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two loops to display the traffic jams, one that goes through the `roadEntries` array and an inner loop that goes through the `trafficJams` array of each road.

To understand loops usage in vue.js, I encourage you to read the [v-for documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

A [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property is also quite handy in this case to filter all the roads that may not have encountered any traffic jams.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      datum: '',
      roadEntries: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    roadEntriesWithTrafficJams() {
        return this.roadEntries.filter(roadEntry => roadEntry.events != null && roadEntry.events.trafficJams != null && roadEntry.events.trafficJams.length > 0);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const api = 'https://www.anwb.nl/feeds/gethf';

    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    axios.get(api).then((response) => {
      this.datum = response.data.dateTime;
      this.roadEntries = response.data.roadEntries;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>
   Date time : {{ datum }}
  </h3>
  <div v-for="roadEntry in roadEntriesWithTrafficJams">
    <h4>
    {{ roadEntry.road }}
    </h4>
    <div v-for="trafficJam in roadEntry.events.trafficJams">
       {{ trafficJam.from }} - {{ trafficJam.to }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have learned a few things out of your comments. In data, I used an object to store everything, but because date is just a string, there's no need to create an object for it. I now know how to use 'filters' and how to display the results. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not the full Vue solution, but I focused on how you might extract the data you need to an array (which can then be looped by v-for) from the API response:

```js
// consider these variables in your Vue data()
let date = '';
const trafficJams = [];

axios.get('https://www.anwb.nl/feeds/gethf')
.then((resp) => {
    date = resp.data.dateTime;
    const roadEntries = resp.data.roadEntries;
    // loop through all roadEntries
    roadEntries.forEach(entry => {
        // extract the trafficJams array to a variable for easier reading
        const jams = entry.events.trafficJams;
        // if there are jams on the given road (entry):
        if (jams.length > 0) {
            // loop through all traffic jam and push the needed data to your variable
            jams.forEach(jam => {
                trafficJams.push({
                    road: entry.road,
                    from: jam.from,
                    to: jam.to
                });
            });
        }
    });
    // and there you have "road", "from" and "to" data for all traffic jams
    console.log(trafficJams);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look at my code. I very much appreciate the notes above every function. They help me understand the correct way of thinking. Your code worked for me.